# How is the functional form of the integral derived?

Tags: integration

I have seen the following integral on the internet: [image]

How is this derived?

I have done searching on Google for days and got no satisfying answer.

In particular, I would like to ask how are integrals related to hypergeometric functions?

And why, when $a=b$, the hypergeometric function reduces to an elementary function?

Also, does the above integral result hold true when $a, b$ are complex numbers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result follows from
$$\begin{split}\mathrm{e}^{ax}\tanh bx &=\mathrm{e}^{ax}\left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^{bx}-\mathrm{e}^{-bx}}{\mathrm{e}^{bx}+\mathrm{e}^{-bx}} \right)\\
&=\mathrm{e}^{ax}\left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^{2bx}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{2bx}+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{(a+2b)x}}{1+\mathrm{e}^{2bx}}-\frac{\mathrm{e}^{ax}}{1+\mathrm{e}^{2bx}}\\
&=\mathrm{e}^{(a+2b)x}\,_1F_0(1;;-\mathrm{e}^{2bx})-\mathrm{e}^{ax}\,_1F_0(1;;-\mathrm{e}^{2bx})\\
\end{split}$$
and
$$\int \mathrm{e}^{ux}\,_1F_0(1;;-\mathrm{e}^{vx})=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{ux}}{u}\,_2F_1(1,\tfrac{u}{v};1+\tfrac{u}{v};-\mathrm{e}^{vx})+C\text{.}$$

In turn, these equalities follow directly from the definition of the hypergeometric series. I expect the original identity to hold for complex $a$ and $b$ such that $2b$ is not a negative multiple of $a$, because for those values denominators in the hypergeometric series become ill-defined. Finally, when $a=b$, the substitution $z=\mathrm{e}^{ax}$ lets one express the integral via elementary methods.

Comment: Your explanation is so clear! Thanks!